# Increase solana compute budget limit in python client

Tags: python, solana

I have this transactions instruction created on python similar to the one written on solana cookbook but in rust.

I'm very curious why the error it returns is not coming with compute limit extension but rather an error of 200000 on 200000 compute limit consumption.

**python**

```
transaction = Transaction()

request_units = CStruct(
"units" / U32,
"additional_fee" / U32   
)


transaction.add(
    TransactionInstruction(
        [],
        compute_program_meta.pubkey,
        request_units.build({"units": 500000, "additional_fee": int(0.01*10**9)})
    )
)

transaction.add(
    TransactionInstruction(
        accounts,
        program_id,
        bytes([0, 10])
    )
)
```

**rust**

```
fn send_instructions_demo(
rpc_client: &RpcClient,
wallet_signer: &dyn Signer,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {{
let accounts = &[];
let txn = submit_transaction(
    &connection,
    &wallet_signer,
    // Array of instructions: 0: Increase Budget, 1: Do something, 2: Do something else
    [ComputeBudgetInstruction::request_units(400_000u32),
    Instruction::new_with_borsh(PROG_KEY, &0u8, accounts.to_vec()),
    Instruction::new_with_borsh(PROG_KEY, &0u8, accounts.to_vec())].to_vec(),
)?;
println!("{:?}", txn);
Ok(())}
```

Comment: See Jacob's response. You can use this on local `solana-test-validator` for now if you are at least on 1.9.8.

Answer (score 3):

The compute budget increase is not released yet on mainnet-beta or devnet. You cannot use it to request more compute until the feature is activated and either cluster releases version `1.9.X`